# Disable "enter" and back link for JavaScript SPA

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, navigation

1. I programmed a SPA with knockoutJS. It contains some forms. If the user presses 'enter' it reloads the whole page. How can I block this?
2. How can I manipulate the back link of the browser. If the user clicks it, it shall just navigate to my main page of the SPA.

Any ideas? Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1):

1. In most of SPA application data interacts with JSON rather than form submit.
   A. To stop form submit return false value. 

   B. If any button is there change there type from submit to button.
2. In SPA application all views should be composed based with unique routes so that history API will have stacked views. Based on user back button clicks it navigated to previous page.

If you want to custmise route then use Hashchange or popstate. Which will give you event to play.

Hope this information will help you.

Comment: Yes I added the following to my code:

`$('html').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });`

It gets recognized when I press enter but it still reloads the form with the default data. How can I block this?

Do you have further information for the second question? Sorry, I am a beginner.